# How to return different responses with a normal and ajax login in spring security 3

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I build a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler so users can login using Ajax aswell use a normal login (for users with javascript disabled). To check if it's an ajax call or normal call I sent an extra request header.
If it is an Ajax call i want to return some different code as on normal request. This results needs to come from a jsp file. I could sent the url back but than the user have to do another request to get the data. How can i read the output of the jsp file from within my code or is this a bad design?

This is how i handle the request.

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException,
    ServletException{
    if ("true".equals(request.getHeader("X-Ajax-call"))) {
        response.getWriter().print("Output of jsp file should go here?");

        response.getWriter().flush();
    } else {
        defaultHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
    }
}
```

Comment: servletRequest.getHeader(X_REQUESTED_WITH) != null
                || servletRequest.getParameter(X_REQUESTED_WITH) != null;
 will check if the request is ajax or not, no need to send additional headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply forward the request:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("myFile.jsp").forward(request, repsponse);
```